# Flutter : execute JavaScript library in native machine (android | IOS) not in webView

Tags: javascript, android, flutter

Is there any possibility to execute JavaScript library (downloaded from NPM repository) in flutter mobile application directly in native machine instead of webView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Dart is compiled to native binary code for Flutter.
You need WebView for JavaScript.

Dart can be compiled to JS, but that is only used for browser apps.